# Can the U.S. government suspend the trading of a stock at any time?

Tags: united-states, china

> HONG KONG (AP) — Trading in shares of heavily indebted Chinese
> property developer China Evergrande Group was suspended in Hong Kong
> on Thursday, according to a notice on the Hong Kong stock exchange.
>
> **China Evergrande said in a notice on Thursday night that authorities
> had informed the firm that its chairman, Hui Ka Yan, had been
> subjected to “mandatory measures in accordance with the law due to
> suspicion of illegal crimes” and said that trading in the firm’s
> shares was suspended until further notice.**
>
> The company didn’t elaborate on the crimes that Hui was suspected of.
>
> Evergrande is the world’s most heavily indebted real estate developer
> and is at the center of a property market crisis that is dragging on
> China’s economic growth.

https://apnews.com/article/china-evergrande-suspends-trading-property-65c2df0510a111475e182350174a065d

From the looks of it, the Chinese government suspended trading of the Evergrande stock. There's not a lot of details on this, but it seems like it's the Chinese government that did it. My question is whether the U.S. government has the same power, and if there's a historical precedent where the U.S. suspended the trading of a particular stock for whatever reason.

Comment: BTW, you left out that "the company [stock] had resumed trading on Aug. 28 after a 17-month hiatus." Although as detailed elsewhere that earlier "suspension" was "for not publishing its financial results."  https://www.theguardian.com/business/2023/sep/28/evergrande-halts-share-trading-as-woes-mount-for-china-property-giant#:~:text=Evergrande%20had%20only%20resumed%20trading,in%20Shenzhen%20on%20unspecified%20charges.

Comment: Also their shares [plunged](https://www.cnbc.com/2023/08/28/china-evergrande-shares-plunge-as-trading-resumes-trade-after-17-months.html) 87% on that August day,. Some stock exchanges have [short term] automatic suspensions for such events. The thresholds may vary, IIRC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The federal securities laws allow the SEC to suspend trading in any stock for up to ten trading days when the SEC determines that a trading suspension is required in the public interest and for the protection of investors

https://www.sec.gov/litigation/suspensions

Comment: While this is a good answer I don't think it addresses the question of doing it at any time as this appears to only happen if certain things happen.

Comment: That's somewhat less than 17 months.